# I need certain courses not covered in my undergraduate studies, can I take them at another institution?

Tags: coursework

I recently got accepted into a graduate CS program (provisionally), but I need to take two classes that my undergraduate studies didn't cover. Now, where I got accepted those courses aren't offered until the fall which poses a problem for me. I would only be able to take one of the graduate courses without those missing courses in the fall.

#### Question:

- Could I take those classes at another institution I'm not enrolled in?
- If so, is there a database I could search comparable CS classes?

I know the standard procedure would be to contact the graduate school's admissions director and see what they recommend, however I feel like I've already annoyed them when I had to defer my summer acceptance. So, I would like them to have all the information needed in order to make that discourse easier for us both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would still suggest you contact the admission director (one more time)! He is the one with the "right" and "only" answer you need to follow. All what we can do is share relevant experiences that may or may not be along the lines of your school's standard/system.

Having said that, If I'm not mistaken, I think you can take the courses in other schools (as long as they are accredited and/or sister schools + cover a similar syllabus as the one your school has). As for a database, try to look through your school's graduate handbook or admission website.

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer. I will mark this as answered in five it seems I have to wait 5 mins. I guess my stackexchange rep doesn't carry over. While, I wait are there any funky procedures to take classes at a school your not going to?

Comment: Your case is very specific, and we can only speculate/share ideas. To be honest, these won't help you that much (and will waste your time!). As for a procedure to take courses, I have not been in your situation before but maybe you can take courses (not offered this term in your school) at a close by community college or even online. I do not know how much of that can be applied to your case thu. I hope somebody can shine in or add some helpful tips.

Comment: It's very important to get prior approval for doing this from the school whose graduate program you will be entering.  They're the ones that will decide whether the course you plan to take is an acceptable substitute for their course.  If they've given you pre-approval, then you can take the course with confidence that it will count.